# Sign in with twitter in zf 2.2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am struggling to find out the way how to implement the sign in in zf 2.2 using

ZendService\Twitter

The application will be used for all the user to have their sign up process done by the twitter only

Please help me with this

Answer (score 3):

`ZendService\Twitter` is the Twitter API implementation: it aims to provide a php component to load tweets from a user, etc. What you are looking for is an identity provider for authentication.

The de facto user module is [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser). This module is extended by [ScnSocialAuth](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth) and provides integration to authenticate a user via Twitter, Facebook, Google etc.

Use those two modules, configure ScnSocialAuth to your needs and you are able to login via Twitter.